# how to typeset a c style function using package algorithm2e?

Tags: algorithm2e

I am very new to type setting algorithms in latex. Following is my first attempt at typesetting a simple c-style function using package algorithm2e:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}
\title{algorithm}
\author{Imran Ali}
\date{June 2017}

\begin{document}
\SetStartEndCondition{(}{)}{)}\SetAlgoBlockMarkers{}{\}}%
\SetKwFunction{Square}{square}%
\SetKwBlock{square}{\{}{}%
\AlgoDisplayBlockMarkers\SetAlgoNoLine%
\begin{algorithm}
\Square(int x)
    \square{%
       result = x ** 2 \;
        }
        \KwRet{result} 
    }
\caption{C style function}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Which produces the following[image]
At the moment the latex compiler is complaining:

> !Extra } or
> forgotten \endgroup

I would appreciate if the community could point out on how to properly achieving the result.

Comment: The package `algorithm2e` is intended for pseudocode, for real code it is usually easier to use `listings` or `minted`.

Comment: @Marijn thanks for mentioning the `listings` and `minted`packages, the output I am trying to achieve is somewhat in between pseudocode and real code as can be found in [Efficiently mining frequent subpaths](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2449366)

Comment: Delete the unmatched `}` above `\caption` and it works.

Comment: @HenriMenke thanks your mentioned resolved the unmatched '}'

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved removing a } as indicated in comments.